# How to make the tab key create 4 spaces in google docs? Or alternatively make the tab character visually be 4 spaces?

Tags: python, tabs, google-docs

I want to recreate my VS Code experience with Python scripts in Google Docs: I have it set up that a tab in VS Code automatically creates exactly 4 spaces. I would like the similar behaviour on Google Docs.

Right now I can set indent to be 4 spaces but every other tab after the indent of the line is going back to the original length of the Google Docs tab.

Any ideas how to fix this? Is there a way to bind the TAB key to automatically just write 4 spaces instead of a "tab" character?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74368/how-to-set-tab-to-generate-4-spaces-every-time-its-pressed-in-google-docs

Comment: Yes I saw that but that doesn't fix my problem. That's an artificial way to create tab stops, doesn't change the default one and you have to do that every time you have a new google docs. I was looking for a more streamlined solution.